# Windows Photo Viewer darkening outside of images

Tags: windows, windows-photo-viewer

I'm assuming there was a software update or something because Windows photo viewer has recently started darkening the outside of images.  Is there any way to turn this "feature" off? [image: darkening the outside of images]

Comment: I cannot see the darkening in your screen shot. Are you talking about the black border because the photo is smaller than Photo Viewer screen size?

Comment: You might have edited the Original Photo to add some "Vignette" or such. Check by opening with Paint or Inserting into Word Document. Also upload Original Photo, to check the Diff.

Comment: Also check in "Settings" where "Automatically Enhance Photos" or such might be enabled.

Comment: Looks like the photo is being adjusted in some way. That application hasn’t been updated in over a year.

Comment: That sure doesn't look like Windows Photo Viewer. W.P.V. is a deprecated program entirely different from the Windows Photo app.

Comment: @John - the photo isn't smaller than the screen size, if you look at the darkened parts of the image there are plot axis

Comment: @Prem - I haven't edited the photos at all I can open them in paint and they look exactly like how I plotted them

Comment: There is not any darkening that I can see from the website as you show it

Comment: It would be good to upload Original Photo. Still, you should check your "Settings" where  "Automatically Enhance Photos" or "Vignette" has been already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that dark mode was enabled auto-enabled. The outside of the plot is transparent, so darkening is actually the background. So I just needed to go into settings and switch to light mode

Comment: This is what I was saying , when I said [[ Also check in **"Settings"** where "**Automatically** Enhance Photos" **or such** might be enabled ]]